# Deploying a debug version of a vb.net app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment

I have developed an application in vb.net.  I use a dll that I build as part of a different project in my solution.  For some reason I don't get the full functionality of my application with the dll built as a "release" version, but it does work if the dll is built as a "debug" version (that's a whole different problem).  I don't have a problem, for now, using the debug version.  However, the problem I'm having is I am trying to deploy the application to another system and if I deploy the debug version of the dll I get a runtime error (see below).  I have the .net Framework installed.  I'm just wondering what has to be installed in order to allow me to use the debug version of the new system?

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at tocapp.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\gregh\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\TOCApp2\TOCApp2\Form1.vb:line 104
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3607 (GDR.050727-3600)
    CodeBase: file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
tocapp
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Sparnet/tocapp.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
SparnetMapControl
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 0.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Sparnet/SparnetMapControl.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Oracle.DataAccess
    Assembly Version: 10.2.0.100
    Win32 Version: 10.2.0.100
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC/Oracle.DataAccess/10.2.0.100__89b483f429c47342/Oracle.DataAccess.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: I have not had problems passing out debug versions of the APP or a DLL. "Debug" mostly means adding "extra" items not *required* for operation. The error above looks more like the real thing. Lets see what your VB code looks like around that line number.

Comment: Is this built from VS2008? If so, which framework are you targeting, 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5? If either of the latter two are they installed on the other machine?  Also, your problem might not be that the remote machine won't run your debug version but instead that the debug version is the only working version and it only works on your machine. I'd sort out the debug/release problem first. Otherwise you might be solving "my tennis skills are bad" by visiting a trainer when really you've got a broken arm.

Comment: I am running VS 2008.  The error seems to be occurring when I try to open a file via a call to functionality provided in a developed dll.  

By the way, I am targeting the 2.0 framework and have it installed on both machines.

Comment: So here is an interesting update given that I am trying to resolve the problem as to why my application works with a debug build of the underlying dll and does not work with a release build of the used underlying dll.  If I change one configuration item of the debug build and use the resulting dll then the functionality does not work. If I change it back then it does work.  So, if I change:

"Configuration Properties" => "C/C++" => "Code Generation" => "Runtime Library

From "Multi-Threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" to "Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)" then the functionality I am looking for no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "underlying dll" might have a bug that is vanishing as soon as you do a debug build; There are many potential causes for this, ranging from thread synchronisation issues (that vanish when `DebugWrite()` calls get removed from Release builds) right the way through to memory corruptions from poorly initiated memory.

Answer (score 0):

> "if I change: "Configuration Properties" => "C/C++" => "Code Generation" => "Runtime Library From "Multi-Threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" to "Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)" then the functionality I am looking for no longer works"

I know this is little old post, but might be usefull to someone.

It seams like linking problem before anything else.
you can't mix libriries for debug with project that does not include debug and also make sure that both dependency libraries are of same build type.
Both libraries and project must be have both same building properties:
debug/multithreaded project must link with debug/multithreaded libraries,
and release/multithreaded project must link with release/multithreaded libraries.

Make sure this is the case in project properties.

also you can't deploy debug version of c++ project since it has to be release. this is since target OS always have release version of c++ runtime libs ;) debug version of c++ dlls is only installed with VS or probably also with some other development environments.

also notice c++ is specific about c++ runtime libs, app without specific manifest file where you have specified range for c++ runtime libs version in most cases explicitly targets c++ runtime libs version against which you have built your app. so make sure you deploy c++ runtime libs redistributable of same version with your app (its ussually around 3mb no big trouble these days).

or link everything statically (larger app, bigger memory foot, hell to setup environment, but no need for shared c++ runtime libs - this is main reason I like deplhi == no dependency).